# emberJS resetting form fields when the user clicks on a browser's forward and back buttons

Tags: button, ember.js, browser, back, forward

I am working on an emberJS application and I have a question regarding a browsers forward and back buttons:
  If a user navigates to a form, then fills out some information, then hits the browser back button, then the forward button, what is the proper way to reset the form so that the fields are blank again?

Do I need to explicitly set the fields to empty string or is there some way I can force a refresh rather than having the browser go to the cache?

Thanks,

Terry

Comment: you could hook into a component's did mount life cycle event? clear the inputs in there?

Comment: didMount?  Does such an event exist?

Comment: I was mostly paraphrasing, but here are the official lifecycle hooks: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/the-component-lifecycle/
you could maybe try setting all the values to empty strings on init or didReceiveAttrs? :)

Comment: Take a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696580/how-to-destroy-and-recreate-a-controller-object-in-ember-framework)

Comment: You could use many things like component hooks OR routes events too. Like resetting all the data with actions (events) `willTransition` (change route), `activate`(enter route) or `deactivate`(leave route)